# text box bug using IE11 and X-UA-Compatible E=Edge on Intranet

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible

We are developing intranet web applications (sites) and to override the inherent IE intranet functionality (running as IE7/compatibility mode) we're using **X-UA-Compatible IE=Edge**. (we have versions with this in the page and in the web.config)

Well ... all was great until very recently when a user (now users) reported problems. The user (and we have replicated) could not get the cursor into ANY text box and so could not type text into the text box .. a pretty big problem :) (all other html controls seem fine).

We have other users with IE11 and everything is still working - we've narrowed the problem ourselves to possibly versions 11.0.9600.17358 and above (below .17358 seem ok). It appears that the very latest versions we're able to upgrade to are showing this problem.

Changing value="IE=Edge" from 'Edge' to '10' or '9' does not help - changing to 'value=8' allows text box entry ... but is not very useful.

(platform: .net4 aspx c# IIS7)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated :) Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested on private sessions?

Comment: Is there any public link where We can test the code.?

Comment: Sorry, there's no public link.
Not sure what you mean by 'tested on private sessions'?

Comment: A private browser session. IE allows you open a private session without cache , cookies and other user data. This could be useful to discard temporary storage issues. Can you create an spike solution replicating the issue?